# How to make firefox overflow accrodion CSS

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm looking for help with my problem with overflowing box in Firefox
Here are some gifs that show my problem.
First gif is in Chrome, which works as I expected (The arrow animation is just not working)
Second gif is in Firefox, which is messed up.

[Chrome GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCczR.gif)

[Firefox GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eO8Op.gif)

```css
.panel{
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;

    .panel-body{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      max-height: calc(100% - 84px); //- is header
      padding: 30px;
      position: relative;
    }

    .accordion {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    .accordion-section {
      &.expanded {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
    }

    .accordion-section-header-container{
      display: block;
      .accordion-header{
        display: flex;
        align-items:center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-direction: row;
      }
    }
    
    .accordion-section-body {
      display: none;
      &.expanded {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        overflow: auto;
      }
    }

    ul.list {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
      overflow-y: auto;
      margin: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <div className="panel">
      <div className="panel-body">
       <div className="accordion">
        <div className="accordion-section">
         <div className="accordion-section-header-container">
          <span className="accodion-header">
            <label>HEADER</label>
            <span classname="arrow"/>
           </div>
          </div>
         <div className=accordion-section-body>
          <ul className="list">
           <li>
            .
            .
            .
            .
           </li>
          </ul>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
```

I already tried everything I thought would work, and I'm still lost. Basically I have a lot of similar problems and I really need to know how to solve this.

Thanks a lot for answers.

Comment: create demo like js fiddle

Comment: Your code does not resemble your gif. Please update your code by replicating the error.

Comment: Thanks for this guys, I will try to make JSfiddle... tomorrow it will be here. ;)